# Jensen–Shannon divergence relation between marginal and joint

Tags: probability, joint-distribution

I have the following distributions-

Joints:

$p_1$(x,y) = $\rho_1$(x) $q_1$(y|x),

$p_2$(x,y) = $\rho_2$(x) $q_2$(y|x)

And the marginals: $\rho_1$(x), $\rho_2$(x).

Is it possible to provide any relation or inequality between the two JSDs:

JSD( $\rho_1$(x) || $\rho_2$(x) ) and JSD( $p_1$(x,y) || $p_2$(x,y) ) ?

Thanks.